# How can I modify the single row in a Datafram while it is returning multiple rows at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with two columns, i.e, Transaction, & Status.

Expected Dataframe:

```
Transaction |   Status
-------------------------
57230477    |   Completed
57232288    |   Completed
57232288    | 
57232288    | 
57228666    |   Completed
57229869    |   Completed
57233318    |   Completed
57233318    |
57227149    |   Completed
57227149    |
57222266    |   Completed
57222266    |
57222266    |
57233319    |   Completed
57233319    |
57230490    |   Completed
```

What is happening in my code is:

```
for txn in df['Transaction'].unique():
    df.loc[df['Transaction'] == txn, 'Status'] = 'Completed'
```

In this case what is happening is, it is assigning the `Status` in all the rows as `Completed`.

What I'm getting:

```
Transaction |   Status
-------------------------
57230477    |   Completed
57232288    |   Completed
57232288    |   Completed
57232288    |   Completed
57228666    |   Completed
57229869    |   Completed
57233318    |   Completed
57233318    |   Completed
57227149    |   Completed
57227149    |   Completed
57222266    |   Completed
57222266    |   Completed
57222266    |   Completed
57233319    |   Completed
57233319    |   Completed
57230490    |   Completed
```

So, my question is how can I just assign the value of `Status` as `Completed` to only the first occurrence of the `Transaction` like in the expected Dataframe at the top, i.e., just assign the values to the unique Transactions and skip the repeating Transactions.

For example `57232288` is repeating 3 times, instead of assigning the `Completed` 3 time assign the value just once at the first occurrence of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `drop_duplicates` and get the index, then assign directly:

```
df.loc[df.drop_duplicates(keep="first").index, "Status"] = "Completed"
print (df)

    Transaction     Status
0      57230477  Completed
1      57232288  Completed
2      57232288           
3      57232288           
4      57228666  Completed
5      57229869  Completed
6      57233318  Completed
7      57233318           
8      57227149  Completed
9      57227149           
10     57222266  Completed
11     57222266           
12     57222266           
13     57233319  Completed
14     57233319           
15     57230490  Completed
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df['Transaction'].duplicated(), "Status"] = "Completed"
print (df)
    Transaction     Status
0      57230477  Completed
1      57232288  Completed
2      57232288        NaN
3      57232288        NaN
4      57228666  Completed
5      57229869  Completed
6      57233318  Completed
7      57233318        NaN
8      57227149  Completed
9      57227149        NaN
10     57222266  Completed
11     57222266        NaN
12     57222266        NaN
13     57233319  Completed
14     57233319        NaN
15     57230490  Completed
```